# How to give two endpoints for one interface in wcf rest?

Tags: wcf

I am working on wcf rest webservices.In that one interface is there having two public methods.i need to access one method in https binding and other one using http.
How to set the endpoint in global.asx for that two bindings.please tell me.

my globlal.asx declaration like this:

```
 RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("records", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(serviceclassname)));
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried and where you've looked for info, and explain why that didn't work? You can edit your question at any time to add more details.